# Angular2 with TensorFlow

Tags: angular, firebase, tensorflow

I have been creating a web application using angular2 with firebase,
I want to know how I can use TensorFlow with Angular2 for the data analysis.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tensorflow.js for your project link in below

https://js.tensorflow.org/